# Does every open affine subscheme of an affine scheme have form $A_f$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let Spec${A}$ be an affine scheme, can every open affine subscheme be written as 
Spec$A_f$ for some $f$ in $A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Counterexamples are discussed at [MO/7153](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7153). The example by Hailong Dao is really elementary: $A=k[X,Y,U,V]/(XY+UX^2+VY^2)$, then $D(X) \cup D(Y)$ is affine, but not basic-open.

Comment: Why is $D(X) \cup D(Y)$ not basic-open? This was not answered over at MO.